# jQuery plugin for shorten long paragraphs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im having a website with long paragraphs, and Im looking for a way to make the initial presentation shorter, so I would like a plugin that gives me the option to expand/contract the text.

I already found something similar, like this: http://jtsnake.github.com/jquery-readmore/ but it doesnt do the rollback funciton.

Is there something similar I could use? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually never made a plugin for this sort of action, so I decided I'd give it a shot, here's what I came up with ->

```
function($){
  $.fn.clipped = function(options){ 
    var settings = $.extend({
      'text' : this.text(),
      'start' : 0,
      'end' : 255,
      'showFrom': 255,
      'readMoreText': 'Read More',
      'readLessText': 'Read Less'     
    }, options);

  return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        var origTxt = settings.text;
    var clippedTxt = origTxt.slice(settings.start, settings.end) + "<div class='read-hidden' style='display:none;opacity:0;'>" + $this.text().slice(settings.showFrom) +"</div><span class='read-clipped'>....<a href='#' class='read-click'>"+settings.readMoreText+"</a></span>";
    $this.html(clippedTxt);

    $('body').on('click', 'a.read-click', function(){
      if($('.read-hidden').css('display') == 'none'){
            //true returned, make changes as necessary.
        $('.read-clipped a').text(settings.readLessText).appendTo($(this).parent('p'));

        //display the rest of the text        
        $('.read-hidden').css('display', 'inline');
        $('.read-hidden').animate({
          opacity:1
        }, 500); 
          //element is shown already, replace the text on next click.  
      }else if($('.read-hidden').css('display') == 'inline'){
        $('.read-hidden').animate({
          opacity:0  
        }, 500, function(){
          $('.read-hidden').css('display', 'none');
          $this.html(clippedText);      
        });
       }
     });
   });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Invoking the plugin is fairly straight forward ->

```
$('#element').clipped({ 
  // clip text at
  'start': 0, 
  //end clipped text at
  'end': 255, 
  //display the rest of the text starting from
  'showFrom': 255, 
  //Read More Text
  'readMoreText' : 'Read More Stuff',
  //Read Less Text 
  'readLessText' : 'Read Less Stuff'
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using same plugin. Open jquery.readmore.js from that plugin zip file you downloaded . and remove the following line of code from the linkage function.

```
$(this).hide();
```

Now the function will be :

```
function linkage(elem) {
      elem.append(opts.more_link);
      elem.find('.' + opts.more_clzz).click( function () {
       elem.find('.' + opts.ellipse_clzz).hide();
        elem.find('.' + opts.hidden_clzz).animate({'opacity' : 'toggle'},1000);
      });
    }
```

On first click it will show the limited chars then shorten again . One more thing you can do is put shorten with read more text:

```
more_link: '<a class="readm-more">Read&nbsp;More/Shorten</a>
```

P.S: If you want i will try to change the text from read more to shorten on click and vice versa.

Comment: The answer by Ohgodwhy did that job. If you need any help further post here.

Comment: it lacks an ellipse customization